# ASP.NET Core 6 "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Rotativa.ViewAsPdf' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult'"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0

I want to make PDF export in my ASP.NET Core 6 project. I use 'Rotativa' and this code to export:

```
public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult Export()
{
    return new ViewAsPdf("PdfReport");
}
```

I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Rotativa.ViewAsPdf' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Please help me - what do I need to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just install 'Rotativa.AspNetCore' package and everything is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IActionResult` instead `ActionResult`

```
public IActionResult Export()
{
    return new ViewAsPdf("PdfReport");
}
```